# How many solutions does the equation have if all variables are positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions does the equation $X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot X_3 \cdot X_4 \cdot X_5 = 2^{20}$ have if all $X_i$'s are positive integers?

So I approached this problem by setting all the $X_i = Y_i + 1$ to get the equation:
$Y_1 \cdot Y_2 \cdot Y_3 \cdot Y_4 \cdot Y_5 = 2^{20} - 5$
Which the solution would be $2^{20} - 1 \choose 5 - 1 $

I think I am doing this wrong though, because the above logic I used on a problem where instead of multiplication it was addition. Does the same logic hold? Sorry for terrible question. I am new to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for the number of **ordered** $5$-tuples $(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_5)$ of positive integers such that $X_1X_2\cdots X_5=2^{20}$. All the $X_i$ must be powers of $2$. Let $X_i=2^{y_i}$. We are looking for the number of $5$-tuples $(y_1,y_2,\dots, y_5)$ of non-negative integers such that $y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_5=20$.

By Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia) this number is $\binom{20+5-1}{5-1}$, or equivalently $\binom{20+5-1}{20}$.

Answer (score 1):

Because you know the prime factorization of the RHS, you have that the x's are all powers of 2. Let's say they are $X_i = 2^{\lambda_i}$, then you get a partition of 20 into 5 parts.

Comment: Ah i see, so once i partition 20 into 5 parts i can then use the logic i used, where it is 5 variables added together to equal 20?